# Backslash SqlServeur Host / Hibernate configuration

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, hibernate, backslash

I'm trying to run my jar file on linux server but I got this error :

*org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The TCP/IP connection to the host HostnameInstanceName, port xxxx has failed.*
Of course the host is not recognized because of the backslash is missing.

My database host is like : hostname\instanceName (with backslash)
I have a file of properties where I put my database properties.

Like :

- dbServer=xxxx\xxxx
- dbDatabase=xxxx
- dbSid=xxxx
- dbSchema=xxxx
- dbUser=xxxx
- dbPassword=xxxx
- dbPort=xxxx
  On my java, I set my sessionFactory with these properties.

`String url : jdbc:sqlserver://" + prop.getDbServer() + ":" + prop.getDbPort() + ";database=" + prop.getDbDatabase());`

Now the problem is, how can I add a backslash between my HostName And InstanceName ?

Thank you for help.

**UPDATE**
I finally solve my problem like that : 1. Change the url on hibernate like that : jdbc:sqlserver://" + prop.getDbServer() + ":" + prop.getDbPort() + ";databaseName="+prop.getDbDatabase()+";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;" 2. Get the ip from this Serveur and replace the serverName by the ip

Comment: Hello everyone *

Comment: Can't you add an additional property like `dbInstance` and modify your `String url` to something like `String url : jdbc:sqlserver://" + prop.getDbServer() + "\" + prop.getDbInstance() + ":" + prop.getDbPort() + ";database=" + prop.getDbDatabase());` ? Or put your `hostname\instanceName` between double quotes?

Comment: If you know the port then just ditch the `\InstanceName`. Instance names are only needed when you don't know the port. They cause the client library to use SQL Server Resolution Protocol to communicate with the SQL Browser service on the target machine, via udp/1434, to resolve the instance name to its listening TCP port number, then the client attempts to connect to the SQL instance using that port number. Since you already have the port number you can just bypass that entire process.

Comment: Hello Thank you for reply guys. 

I finally solve my problem like that : 

1. Change the url on hibernate like that : 

`jdbc:sqlserver://" + prop.getDbServer() + ":" + prop.getDbPort() + ";databaseName="+prop.getDbDatabase()+";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"`

2. Get the ip from this Serveur and replace the serverName by the ip.